# Cannot access and print byte array in index in mips

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to print a random byte to the screen to just check to see if I'm getting the right element. I use li $v0, 11 since its a byte but apparently, you can lw and then use a byte value, but I tried that and it doesn't work as well. It prints out an address like 268501003 for example at the current row + col index i set it to, and the address does change depending on the arguments i set to $a0 and $a1 prior to calling calculate address. But I'm getting no output for the array index value I'm trying to print. PLEASE HELP!

```
.data

N: .word 10  # gives board dimensions

board:
   .byte 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
   .byte 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
   .byte 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
   .byte 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
   .byte 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
   .byte 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0
   .byte 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0
   .byte 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
   .byte 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
   .byte 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

newBoard: .space 100

.data

maxiter: .word 0
nn: .word 0
promptMsg: .asciiz "# Iterations: "
dot: .asciiz "."
newLine: .asciiz "\n"
.text
#===============================
main: 
la $a0, promptMsg
jal printText

li $v0, 5
syscall

li $a0, 6 #random row/col index
li $a1, 7
la $a2, board
jal calculate_address

move $t5, $v0

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t5
syscall

la $a0, newLine
jal printText

li $t7, 0
li, $a0, 0
lb $t7, board($t5)
move $a0, $t7
li $v0, 11
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall

printText:
li $v0, 4
syscall
jr $ra 

calculate_address:
#(Row Index * Column Size + Column Index)*dataSize + base address
#a0 = rowIndex, a1 = colIndex, a2 = base address
lw $t6, N # col size
li $t3, 0
mult $a0, $t6
mfhi $t3
add $t3, $t3, $a1
add $t3, $t3, $a2
#la $a0, msg4
#jal printText
move $v0, $t3 #return address of element [i][j]
jr $ra
```

Comment: System call 11 prints _characters_. ASCII 0 and 1 correspond to NUL and SOH, both of which are nonprintable characters. Use system call 1 if you want to print an integer.

Comment: thanks. as i mentioned though even if i change it to 1, and change the storing of the data value I'm printing to lw (or keep it as lb), it's not printing anything

Comment: Well, you've got an exception at `lb $t7, board($t5)` (which I suspect the simulator has told you about). You should fix that before you continue with anything else.

Comment: oh thanks i didnt actually see that. i wonder why that is though...

Comment: `$t5` contains a value greater than the size of the `board` array.

Comment: `mfhi $t3` shouldn't this be just `mflo`, as you are multiplying values like 7 * 10? (= 700 = will fit very well into low word (32 bits = max cca +-2^31)).

Comment: And the `syscall` is not obliged to preserve values in `$tX` registers, so your debug output is probably changing `t5` value. If you are interested into particular value in register during calculation, use the debugger and step over single calculation step (CPU instruction), then you can check CPU state (register values) without affecting anything (and even check memory view to see values stored in [stack/general] memory).